# Как можно проверить, является ли символ буквой?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, стек

Как можно проверить является ли символ буквой? Если да считать следующие буквы до скобки, если нет, поместить в стек. С регулярными выражениями знаком плохо. Если можно как-то сделать это через обычное условие, то тоже подойдет.

Comment: регулярка на подобе [aA-zZ][аА-яЯёЁ]

Comment: Character.isLetter( ch );

Comment: Может покажите строку которую парсите и опишите что с ней нужно сделать?

Comment: @Z.John делаю постфиксный калькулятор на основе обратной полькой нотации. Строка может быть любой. Хочу вычленить из строки формулы типа sin cos и т.д и запихать их в стек.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
        Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();

        StringBuilder sb  = new StringBuilder(); 
        for(char ch : str.toCharArray()){
            if(!Character.isLetter( ch )){
                stack.add( sb.toString() );
                sb = new StringBuilder();
            }else{
                sb.append(ch);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Код НЕ компилируется, так как в стек _символов_ записывается _строка_.  Код для каждого небуквенного символа забивает стек пустыми строками, каждый раз создавая новый экземпляр `StringBuilder`.  Плодить `StringBuilder` необязательно, вызов `StringBuilder::toString` создаст новую _неизменяемую строку_.  Для очистки экземпляра `StringBuilder` достаточно вызвать `sb.setLength(0);`

Answer (score 1):

```
function isLetter(ch) {
  return ch.toLowerCase() !== ch.toUpperCase();
}

console.log(
  isLetter('a'), // true
  isLetter('B'), // true
  isLetter('1'), // false
  isLetter(','), // false
  isLetter(' '), // false
);
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: У вас ответ на JavaScript написан :)  В целом остроумно, хотя в джаве есть стандартный метод `Character::isLetter`

Comment: Проблема вашего кода в том, что в юникоде есть достаточно много букв (title case letters, other letters), к примеру арабский алфавит / иврит, для которых неприменимо понятие lower case/upper case.